# Backspace and Shift key not working in UbuntuStudio 16.04 LTS upgraded from UbuntuStudio 14.04 LTS

Tags: upgrade, keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout

I am using UbuntuStudio 16.04 LTS upgraded from 14.04. Backspace and Left Shift key stop working. Not getting any error message in terminal when pressing Backspace.
I am using 
Samsung R430 Laptop
LANG=en_IN
LANGUAGE=en_IN:en
Operating System: UbuntuStudio 16.04 LTS xfce

Comment: Which keyboard layout are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You can map any key to any function using `xmodmap`. In your case, open a terminal and run:

```
 xmodmap -e 'keycode 22=BackSpace'
 xmodmap -e 'keycode 50=Shift_L'
 xmodmap -e 'keycode 62=Shift_R'
```

For reference, to list the full binding of your keyboard, type `xmodmap -pk`.

More information about this tool [here](https://www.x.org/archive/X11R6.8.2/doc/xmodmap.1.html).

Comment: sorry, it not solved the problem