# Ctrl keys not working - 16.04 LTS, Cougar 200k keyboard

Tags: 16.04, keyboard

I have a fresh install of Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and a Cougar 200k keyboard.

As far as I can tell all keys and functions are working, except the two <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> keys.

Not having <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> keys kinda sucks ;)

Any ideas?

UPDATES:

1. Both <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> keys act like additional <kbd>Shift</kbd> keys
2. Tried this code(https://bitbucket.org/Swoogan/aziokbd), but it didn't solve the problem
3. --  Did the blacklist as described for aziokbd, but it did not solve the problem.
4. Tested the keycodes using showkey and xev: Ctrl, Shift, and Alt all have the same keycode. showkey returns 42, and xev returns 50

Comment: If you run `sudo showkey`  and hold Ctrl (ether one).  What happens?

Comment: It tells me I pressed the key code 42 (see edit)

Comment: Could  this here help you? http://askubuntu.com/questions/648798/ctrl-and-alt-works-as-shift
Frankly, I'm no big fan of fixing issues like that, but if it works... :-/

Comment: "2 his code: https://bitbucket.org/Swoogan/aziokbd, but it didn't solve the problem" -  Did you blacklist the usbhid as per instructions.  You can't just copy/paste the code written there.  `usbhid.quirks=0x0c45:0x7603:0x4` must match the ID given for your keyboard by `lsusb`.

Comment: "_Did you blacklist the usbhid as per instructions. You can't just copy/paste the code written there._"

I just did the blacklist, but to no effect.

Comment: Okay... I have no more ideas.  I upvoted the question. Perhaps others have more ideas.

Comment: You can change it with `xmodmap`. I don't have my Ubuntu here at the moment to give you the full solution, but see [my answer here](http://askubuntu.com/a/812233/308164). Just find the correct number of the actual control keys (using `xev` maybe) and map them accordingly.

Comment: Turns out, ctr, shift, and alt all have the same keycode...

Answer (score 0):

Just install the [aziokbd driver](https://github.com/teitss/aziokbd), it worked for me:

```shell
sudo apt-get install mercurial build-essential linux-headers-generic dkms
git clone https://github.com/teitss/aziokbd
cd aziokbd
./install.sh
```

Make sure to plug it out after installing the driver then plug it in again.